# Display for template for an empty list

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, display-templates

I have a view with a model, this model contains a list of items.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">@Resources.StatusMessage</h3>
    </div>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.StatusMessages.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.StatusMessages[i])
    }
    <div class="panel-footer">
        @Html.ActionLink(Resources.AddStatusMessage, "AddStatusMessage", new {Id = Model.Id})
    </div>
</div>
```

This List is displayed using a DisplayFor template. The template is based on the item in the list and the displayFor simply loops over it.

The problem is that when the list is empty i'd like to have a placeholder string that says "No status messages".

I'm looking for a way to add this placeholder preferably using the already existing display for template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried the bellow

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">@Resources.StatusMessage</h3>
    </div>
    @if(!Model.StatusMessages.Any()){@Html.DisplayFor(m => "Your string message here")}
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.StatusMessages.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.StatusMessages[i])
    }
    <div class="panel-footer">
        @Html.ActionLink(Resources.AddStatusMessage, "AddStatusMessage", new {Id = Model.Id})
    </div>
</div>`
```

Comment: this seems like it'll do the trick. Altough i'm still strugling to find the border between logic that is allowed in the view and logic that should strictly be in the controller

Answer (score 1):

If you using Templates you can do it simplier:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">@Resources.StatusMessage</h3>
    </div>
    @if(Model.StatusMessages != null && Model.StatusMessages.Any())
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.StatusMessages)
    }
    else
    {
        <p>No status messages</p>
    }
    <div class="panel-footer">
        @Html.ActionLink(Resources.AddStatusMessage, "AddStatusMessage", new {Id = Model.Id})
    </div>
</div>
```

You don't need loop becouse Razor templates iterate collection for you.

Comment: Model contains a List he says.

Comment: @Valkyriee i know. What i talking about is that Razor templates work with lists even if you only have template for one element

Comment: this looks like the best option but i maybe should've mentioned in the original post that i was going to add an eidt and delete button aswel. For that i need the id's and so the loop is still required

Comment: @AxelBouttelgier indeed if you need Ids - go for loop

Comment: @AxelBouttelgier another option - just add Id field to yout Message model

Answer (score 1):

A simple If would do the trick:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">@Resources.StatusMessage</h3>
    </div>
    @{
      if(Model.StatusMessages != null)
      {
        for (int i = 0; i < Model.StatusMessages.Count; i++)
        {
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.StatusMessages[i])
        }
      }
      else
      {
       @Html.Display("No Status")
      }
     }

    <div class="panel-footer">
        @Html.ActionLink(Resources.AddStatusMessage, "AddStatusMessage", new {Id = Model.Id})
    </div>
</div>
```